# Recursion and a counter variable in a binary tree

Tags: recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Following are 2 codes:
 1. Find the kth smallest integer in a binary search tree:

```
void FindKthSmallest(struct TreeNode* root, int& k)
{
  if (root == NULL) return;
  if (k == 0) return; // k==0 means target node has been found
  FindKthSmallest (root->left, k);

  if (k > 0) // k==0 means target node has been found
  {
    k--;
    if (k == 0) { // target node is current node
    cout << root->data;
    return;
    } else {
    FindKthSmallest (root->right, k);
    }
  }
}
```

2. Find the number of nodes in a binary tree:

   ```
   int Size (struct TreeNode* root)
   {
     if (root == NULL) return 0;
     int l = Size (root->left);
     int r = Size (root->right);
     return (l+r+1);
   }
   ```

My Question:
In both these codes, I will have to keep track of the number of nodes I visit. Why is it that code 1 requires passing a parameter by reference to keep track of the number of nodes I visit, whereas code 2 does not require any variable to be passed by reference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first code (1) is looking for the smallest node in your BST. You search from the root down the left side of the tree since the smallest valued node will be found in that location. You make several checks:

- `root == null` - to determine if the tree is empty.
- `k == 0` - zero in this case is the smallest element. You are making this assumption based on whatever principles are apart of this tree.

Then you recursively traverse the list to find the next smallest in the left side of the tree. You perform one more check that if `k > 0` you decrement k `<-` this is why you need to pass by reference since you are making changes to some value `k` given by a separate function, global variable, etc. If `k` happens to be zero then you have found the smallest valued node, if not you go one right of the current node and then continue the process from there. This seems like a very arbitrary way of finding the smallest node...

For the second code (2) you are just counting the nodes in your tree starting at the root and counting each subsequent node (either left or right) recursively until no more nodes can be found. You return your result which is the total amount of left nodes,right nodes. and + 1 for the root since it was not counted earlier. In this instance no passed by reference variable is needed although you could potentially implement one if you choose to do so.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Passing the parameter by reference allows you to keep track of the count within the recursive process, otherwise the count would reset. It allows you to modify the data within the memory space, thus changing the former value not the current/local value.